# Should I use a canonical link which refers to the current URL with pagination?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, google-index, canonical-url, pagination

*I know there are similar questions to this, but they either did not cover what I was looking for or I did not understand them fully, therefore I am asking this here.*

**My situation**

At the moment I am using rel prev and rel next as pagination.

```
<link rel="prev" href="http://www.example.com/category/blablabla/page/2" />
<link rel="next" href="http://www.example.com/category/blablabla/page/4" />
```

I currently also add a canonical link which refers to the first page, i.e:

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/category/blablabla" rel="canonical">
```

**The problem**

The situation is like this:

The first page has only 20 items (as all other pages do).

With this canonical link i.e to the first page, only the first page gets indexed by Google.

I would like all the pages to get indexed because important content might get lost if they are not indexed.

**Should I just change the canonical link to the current URL? i.e the current page, in this case:**

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/category/blablabla/page/3" rel="canonical">
```

**Or should I do something else, if yes, then what would it be?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't set your `canonical` to the first, but to the current page, [like big G said](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html).

Comment: Your link does not work Evgeniy

Comment: @MichaelMoriarty works again. Look at MistakeNumber1. But its true - previous link isn't there.

Comment: @Evgeniy Thanks for the answer. However, the big G link you shared gives an example of a "long text article" spread across multiple pages, and the content of that article remains static. The GBlogPost does not talk about listings (like that of items on a shopping site) which may be a bit dynamic depending upon change in prices, availability, sorting order, etc. Actually the original q is also abt the item list and not about the static article. In that case, should all page2 onward refer to first page (which will be the landing page from search engine)? Please share ur thoughts